# Postgresql command line utility dosen't start on WSL

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using windows subsystem for linux with ubuntu 18.04; I'm trying to use Postgresql on my machine, I've taken care of the relevant installations. 
But when I enter the command: `sudo -u postgres psql`, it asks for my sudo password, and then the cursor blinks on forever. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: what happens if you first run `sudo -u postgres` then enter `psql` on the next prompt?

Comment: When I hit 'sudo -u postgres', I get usage list, then when I hist 'pasq', the cursor blinks forever. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Can you do `sudo -u postgres bash`?

Comment: Yes. @a_horse_with_no_name